# VBA to exort chart from excel tab to specific folder and name file based on a name in a cell on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, image, charts, export

I have a macro that exports a chart as an image to a specific folder, but it gives a fixed name. How can I change the macro to name the file after cell Y3 in a sheet named "Data"?

I tried this: Filename = "C:\Report\" & Sheets("Data").Range("Y3") & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG" and it did not work.

```
Sub ExportGraphImage()

Worksheets("CIS Graph").ChartObjects(1) _
.Chart.Export _
Filename:="C:\Report\CISgraph.jpg",FilterName:="JPG"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I expected that it would help to qualify the cell definition with its `Value` property? The following worked for me (as did the original command). Of course, I also would use `Worksheets()` instead of `Sheets()`, but I'm funny that way.

```
Filename = "C:\Report\" & Sheets("Data").Range("Y3").Value & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG"
```

But as it turns out, it worked for me without `.Value`, so maybe there is a problem with what's in the cell, or the name of the sheet (like if it's really "Data  ").

And by the way, PNG is generally a better format to use for graphics like an Excel chart.